# Java TextArea and String (print only 1 word of String)

Tags: java, string, swing, printing, textarea

I got problem with my TextArea
String A contain text a,b,c,d
I converted String to textarea using method TextArea.setText(A);
My problem is that textarea print out abcd instead of it I want it printed in lines example

```
A
B 
C
D
```

I did read book and tried google but I can't find solution to my problem ;(

Comment: so, basically you want to convert `a,b,c,d` into `A B C D`(each alphabet on a new line) and set it as textArea ??

Comment: So, you want to convert commas to end of lines, and lowercase letters to uppercase letters? What have you tried? Have you read the [javadoc of the String class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)?

Comment: I just want those words in new line (after ","), textarea print everything without space making it look like one big word and I want every word printed in new line

Comment: Then if that is the case is should be `TextArea.setText(a.replace(",", "\n"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to follow the javadoc that JB Nizet linked to above, and take advantage of the String.replace() method.  It takes two CharSequences, first the characters to match, the second the characters to replace it with.  Find the ", " and replace with "\n".  So

```
CharSequence theseChars = new CharSequence(", ");
CharSequence withTheseChars = new CharSequence("\n");

String newString = A.replace(theseChars, withTheseChars);
```

And that should get the job done.

Comment: `String` *is a* `CharSequence`. Just use `String newString = A.replace(",", "\n")`.

Comment: True True.  Just being very explicit.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the most basic stuff of Java.
I think this is easy to understand

`String s = "a,b,c,d";`

`String s1 =s.replace(",", "");`

`String s2 = s1.replace("", "\n").toUpperCase();`